# Lighthouse modify HTML report - add screenshot

Tags: lighthouse

I am rather new to lighthouse. I am using lighthouse from the Windows PowerShell with the command

```
lighthouse https://mywebsite.com/ --locale=es
```

I need to modify the HTML report that the tool generates and attach a screenshot of the webpage at the top of the report.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You can [generate a Lighthouse report programmatically](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/5269), take a screenshot with Puppeteer and inject the image in the generated HTML.

Here are some [recipes on how to use Puppeteer and Lighthouse together](https://addyosmani.com/blog/puppeteer-recipes/#lighthouse-report), and here is an example that shows how to [manipulate the HTML report generated by Lighthouse](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/3d813ed5867412ab55517ba77eb5f93a).